# Ubuntu 18.04 Emergency mode problem

Tags: boot, 18.04

When I tried to start my computer, it boots in emergency mode and shows some problem. I don't know about these problem. if I run 'exit' command that again brings back the emergency mode. [This is shown by system in first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnviZ.jpg)

[After running 'exit' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J4xO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last night and I fixed it using the following steps:

*Before starting it would be safe to backup all your data, though I didn't and came out of the problem without losing anything.*

1. First you **must boot into your system using a live cd/usb** and **make sure you have all other devices unmounted** from the system.
2. Run this  `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/<partition_id>`
3. **Repeat step 2. for each and every partition you have** until you find the corrupted one.
4. Upon finding the problem, it will show you something like this:

   `Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.`

   `Home: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options)`
5. Then **run** `sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/<corrupted_partition_id>`
6. **Press 'y'** on every prompt to fix them.
7. **Reboot** after completion of the full recovery process.

For a detailed information you may look into [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336395)